# How to use Roboto Condensed font?

Tags: fonts

It's a very nice font and available from [Google Font](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Roboto+Condensed). Is it a way I can use it? Many tanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Download the font: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/roboto
2. Install it into your system.
3. Typeset the following using xelatex or lualatex:

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Roboto Condensed}
\begin{document}
\textsf{Domo arigato, Mr. Roboto.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where shall I put the fonts to? the root of MikTex?

Comment: Install them so that they're available to Windows and they'll then be accessible to everything --- I believe that you can place them in your texmf or localtexmf tree in the appropriate place and refresh your font list and they'll then work --- check the MikTeX docs.

Comment: First option is to copy it to Control Panel/Fonts or equivalently C:\Windows\Fonts. Second option is to copy them to `<texmf>\fonts\truetype` where `<texmf>` is one of the directories listed in MiKTeX Settings (not the admin version) and run `texhash` in the command line afterwards.