# How to use fontspec package in LaTex

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I installed MikTeX from here: https://miktex.org/download. It seems to be the recommended program to install all LaTex related things.

I wanted to use a custom Google Font so I followed this question: [How to use Roboto Condensed font?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149565/how-to-use-roboto-condensed-font) and added the following lines to the `tex_template.tex` file:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Roboto Condensed}
```

However, I kept getting errors. So, I did a little research and came to know about XeLaTex from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525779/how-do-i-use-truetype-fonts-with-latex

It says that `MiKTeX is XeLaTeX ready.` and `It's simple as \setmainfont{Lucida Sans Unicode}`.

I have added this line at the top of my `.tex` file:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
%\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Roboto Condensed}
\DisableLigatures{encoding = *, family = * }
```

However, I kept getting the following error in error log:

```
! Fatal Package fontspec Error: The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or
(fontspec)                      LuaTeX.
(fontspec)                      
(fontspec)                      You must change your typesetting engine to,
(fontspec)                      e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"instead of
(fontspec)                      "latex" or "pdflatex".
```

How can I use the fontspec package to use a custom Google Font in my LaTex?

After reading the comment by David and a bit of my own research, I opened TexWorks and made the following changes:

[image]

My `tex` document now has the following lines:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
%\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Roboto Condensed}
\DisableLigatures{encoding = *, family = * }
```

However, I still get the same error in the error log:

```
! Fatal Package fontspec Error: The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or
(fontspec)                      LuaTeX.
(fontspec)                      
(fontspec)                      You must change your typesetting engine to,
(fontspec)                      e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"instead of
(fontspec)                      "latex" or "pdflatex".

Type <return> to continue.
 ...                                              

l.45 \msg_fatal:nn {fontspec} {cannot-use-pdftex}
```

Thanks.

Comment: you need to use xelatex (miktex includes pdflatex and xelatex and lualatex) and also remove these lines which are just for pdflatex \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle. :)

I did this:

```Start TeXworks, choose Edit: Preferences: Typesetting, and change the drop-down box Default to “XeLaTex+MakeIndex+BibTeX”.``` and then removed `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` from my .tex file.

Comment: However, the error log still displays the same message.

Comment: How does the main menu of texworks look when you click on the compile button?