# LaTeX command is already defined error

Tags: xetex, fontspec, unicode-math, math-fonts, mathspec

This is the part of my LaTeX file where I load all the packages:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
%\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Ubuntu}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Ubuntu}
```

However, it gives me the error:

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\amssymb.sty"
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty"
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
)

! LaTeX Error: Command `\eth' already defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.240 ...ol{\eth}            {\mathord}{AMSb}{"67}
```

The document contains the following lines:

```
\begin{document}

YourTextHere

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some comments and observations:

- It's a good idea to load math font packages such as `amssymb`, `dsfont`, `mathrsfs` and `wasysym` *before* loading `unicode-math`. For sure, if you follow this piece of advice, the

  ```
  ! LaTeX Error: Command `\eth' already defined.
  ```

  error messages will cease.
- The `unicode-math` package works under both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, and it loads `fontspec` automatically. AFAICT, though, `unicode-math` is not really compatible with the older, XeLaTeX-only `mathspec` package. My suggestion: don't load `fontspec` and `mathspec`.

  To wit, here's an excerpt from the user guide of the `mathspec` package:

[image]

- I would attempt to provide a more rational structure on the preamble, maybe along the following lines. Whatever else you do, please do yourself a big favor and figure out which packages are truly needed -- and which ones are pure fluff and hence shouldn't be loaded.

---

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article} % any good reason for loading 'standalone'?

%% math and physics packages:
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{wasysym}

%% other packages
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{calligra} % are you serious?!
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{relsize}
%\usepackage{textcomp} % has recently become part of LaTeX 'core'
\usepackage{tipa} % are you absolutely sure you need this package?
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{microtype}

%\usepackage{mathspec} % conflicts with 'unicode-math'
%\usepackage{fontspec} % is loaded automatically by 'unicode-math'

\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman} % I don't have 'Ubuntu' font
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}
Hello World.
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up comment. Thanks for clarifying the purpose of the `\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Ubuntu}` statement. Let me thus reformulate one the suggestions given above: Do load the `mathspec` package -- and don't load the `unicode-math` package.

Comment: Thanks @Mico. :)

The LaTex document is part of a larger library and I am pretty new to LaTex so I did not know if there are any obsolete or extra packages in the file.

Comment: I wanted to use `fontspec` and `mathspec` so that the font of regular text and the letters/digits in the Mathematical formulae looked the same. I followed the instructions in this question to do that: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149565/how-to-use-roboto-condensed-font.

Comment: The LaTex now compiles without an error but most of the document is now empty instead of any actual text. :)

Comment: @RealNoob - Using the "regular", i.e., text-mode letters and numerals in math expressions is perfectly feasible under `unicode-math`. I'll post an addendum to show how that may be done. It'll have to be with Latin Modern,. though, as I don't have the 'Ubuntu' fonts on my system.

Comment: Thanks @Mico. :)

Comment: I have no idea why the tex document says `\documentclass[preview]{standalone}`. However, replacing it with `\documentclass{article}` prevented the text from rendering properly.

When I started using `\documentclass[preview]{standalone}`, all the text rendered as expected. Maybe that's just how the larger framework works with LaTex. :)

Most of the times, I just have to deal with a specific part of the framework so I leave everything else like LaTex untouched. :)

Comment: @RealNoob - Since you've given no hint as to what's between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, I'm in no position to speculate as to why `\documentclass{article}` would prevent the  text from rendering properly. Please also see the addendum I just posted.

Comment: The document only contains `YourTextHere` between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. This is latex replaced by LaTeX that I write in other part of the framework. :)

Comment: Is there anything that I have to keep in mind after replacing `unicode-math` with the `mathspec` package? Thanks.

Comment: @RealNoob - Since I don't have any information about the math material in your document, I'm afraid I'm not in a position to give meaningful advice as to "anything you should keep in mind".

Comment: @RealNoob You have to keep in mind that `mathspec` is an extensive hack and you'll need several small adjustments after looking at the typeset output.