# moderncv and xelatex command definition clash

Tags: xetex, moderncv

Tried to compile this sample code on my machine using xelatex (W10, new installation of miktex).

It gave an error "LaTeX Error: Command `\eth' already defined".

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[english,12pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}
Hello World.
\end{document}
```

Changing the class to article eliminates this error, but I want to use moderncv and xelatex.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is technically covered in [LaTeX command is already defined error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/547150/5764), since [`moderncv`](//ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) loads `unicode-math`. So you can either use

```
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\documentclass[...]{moderncv}
%...
```

or

```
\documentclass[...]{moderncv}
%...
\let\eth\relax
\let\digamma\relax
\let\backepsilon\relax
\usepackage{amssymb}
%...
```

The latter option removes any commands that would have been defined already that [`amssymb`](//ctan.org/pkg/amssymb) tries to (re)define.

Comment: Thanks! that's extremely helpful.